# скрипт для всех полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который считает количество символов в `input`. Если добавить поле,  то скрипт работает некорректно. 
В чем может быть причина?

```js
function inputSymbolCounter() {
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".symbol-input__counter");
  for (var i = 0; elem.length > i; i++) {
    var maxValueInputInit = elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number").textContent;
    var maxValueInit = parseFloat(maxValueInputInit);
    elem[i].querySelector(".symbol-counter__input").setAttribute("maxlength", maxValueInit);
    elem[i].querySelector(".symbol-counter__input").oninput = function(e) {
      var maxValueInput = elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number").textContent;
      var maxValue = parseFloat(maxValueInput);
      if (e.target.value.length > maxValueInit) {
        return false;
      } else {
        elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number").innerHTML = maxValueInit - e.target.value.length;
      }
    };
  }
}
inputSymbolCounter();
```

```css
.features-elem__field {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}

.features-elem__field-textarea {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
}

.features-elem__input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 35px !important;
  padding-right: 125px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.features-elem__input:active,
.features-elem__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5ed1b5;
}

.features-elem__symbols {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: #5ed1b5;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-elem__field symbol-input__counter">
  <input type="text" class="features-elem__input symbol-counter__input" maxlength>
  <div class="features-elem__symbols">
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-arrow">&#60;</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-number">15</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-text">sym</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="features-elem__field symbol-input__counter">
  <input type="text" class="features-elem__input symbol-counter__input" maxlength>
  <div class="features-elem__symbols">
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-arrow">&#60;</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-number">35</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-text">sym</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка происходит из-за некорректного обращения с `var` и замыканиями.
 Из-за того что `var` [хойстится (hoisting)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) на верх до определения функции, переменная `i` после окончания цикла становится равной `elem.length`, соответственно `elem[i]` указывает на несуществующий индекс. Обработчик события `oninput` срабатывает только после завершения цикла, значение переменной `i` берется через ссылку на область видимости (через замыкание) родительской функции, в `i` у него будет равно `elem.length`.

**Пара замечаний:**

1. Для предотвращения действия по умолчанию лучше вызывать [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). `return false` работает только если обработчик добавляется через "on<событие>", что может вызвать ошибки если в будущем изменится способ привязки события.
2. Кроме того постоянно вызывать `querySelector` для получения одних и тех же узлов крайне нежелательно, т.к. обход DOM дерева довольно дорогая операция. Лучше один раз выбрать узел и сохранить его в локальную переменную. Это также улучшит читаемость кода.

**Решение:**
Проблему с замыканием можно решить одним из перечисленных способов:

1. Запоминать значение переменной при помощи создания дополнительного замыкания

   ```
   for (var i = 0; elem.length > i; i++) {
      var maxValueNode = elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number")
      var maxValueInit = parseFloat(maxValueNode.textContent);

      var counterNode = elem[i].querySelector(".symbol-counter__input");

      counterNode.setAttribute("maxlength", maxValueInit);
      counterNode.oninput = (function(maxValueNode, maxValueInit){ return function(e) {
        //Создаём отдельное замыкание на каждую итерацию, 
        //для сохранения значений maxValueInit и maxValueNode.
        if (e.target.value.length > maxValueInit) {
          e.preventDefault();

        } else {
          maxValueNode.innerHTML = maxValueInit - e.target.value.length;

        }
      }})(maxValueNode, maxValueInit);
    }
   ```
2. Прибиндить (сделать bind с доп. параметрами) `oninput` значения i или интересующих вас узлов.

```js
function inputSymbolCounter() {
   
   var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".symbol-input__counter");
   for (var i = 0; elem.length > i; i++) {
  var maxValueNode = elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number")
  var maxValueInit = parseFloat(maxValueNode.textContent);

  var counterNode = elem[i].querySelector(".symbol-counter__input");

  counterNode.setAttribute("maxlength", maxValueInit);
  
  counterNode.oninput = function(maxValueNode, maxValueInit, e) { 
  // Бинд сохранит для нас значения переданных переменных
  // и передаст их в качестве первых агрументов функции при её вызове.
      if (e.target.value.length > maxValueInit) {
         e.preventDefault();

      } else {
         maxValueNode.innerHTML = maxValueInit - e.target.value.length;
      }
  }.bind(this, maxValueNode, maxValueInit); 
   }
}
inputSymbolCounter()
```

```css
.features-elem__field {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
}

.features-elem__field-textarea {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
}

.features-elem__input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 35px !important;
  padding-right: 125px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.features-elem__input:active,
.features-elem__input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5ed1b5;
}

.features-elem__symbols {
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: #5ed1b5;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-elem__field symbol-input__counter">
  <input type="text" class="features-elem__input symbol-counter__input" maxlength>
  <div class="features-elem__symbols">
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-arrow">&#60;</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-number">15</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-text">sym</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="features-elem__field symbol-input__counter">
  <input type="text" class="features-elem__input symbol-counter__input" maxlength>
  <div class="features-elem__symbols">
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-arrow">&#60;</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-number">35</span>
    <span class="features-elem__symbols-text">sym</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Заменить запомнить значения `elem[i]` в переменной с `let` или `const` и использовать их внутри `oninput`. `let` и `const` создаются в области видимости цикла, поэтому каждый обработчик в цикле будет импть со

   ```
   function inputSymbolCounter() {
     const elem = document.querySelectorAll(".symbol-input__counter");
     for (let i = 0; elem.length > i; i++) {
       // Переменные объявленные через const или let не хойстятся.
       // Они создаются на каждой итерации заново. 
       // Благодаря этому обработчики получают значения которые были на сомент их создания
       const maxValueNode = elem[i].querySelector(".features-elem__symbols-number")
       const maxValueInit = parseFloat(maxValueNode.textContent);

       const counterNode = elem[i].querySelector(".symbol-counter__input");

       counterNode.setAttribute("maxlength", maxValueInit);
       counterNode.oninput = function(e) {
         if (e.target.value.length > maxValueInit) {
           e.preventDefault();

         } else {
           maxValueNode.innerHTML = maxValueInit - e.target.value.length;

         }
       };
     }
   }
   inputSymbolCounter();
   ```

Comment: можно пожалуйста показать как без es6 сделать

Comment: у меня старый проэкт, где es6 не потдерживаеться

Comment: Решения расположены по возрастанию требованиям к браузеру. 
Первый вариант должен работать даже на es3. Второе требует поддержки es5 (для bind, но его можно эмулировать на es3). Только третий вариант требует es6.

Comment: всё я понял спс, я не сразу понял что вы несколько версий написали